Remove JHipster Registry from JHipster micro service
We are using a JHipster microservice with JHipster registry 6.1.1 in our production. Since the JHipster registry was officially deprecated, we would like to move to different registry providers like K8s DNS lookup.
However, when we disable the Eureka service registry for the gateway application, the admin UI does not launch properly, and some of the functionalities do not work.
Can we use JHipster microservices with K8s DNS lookup?
Is there any migration guide available to migrate from the JHipster service registry to Consul or K8s?
